# Trying to convert column headings which are in datetime.datetime format 2016-09-01 00:00:00 to datetime.datetime format to '2016-09-01'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have imported data from excel file using pandas and cleaned it. But the problem I am facing right now is that all my columns have headings in the datetimeformat, which is like this, '2016-09-01 00:00:00', but I just need this format '2016-09-01'. These are the codes I am using:

```
import pandas
df7 = pandas.read_excel("abc.XLSX",  sheetname = 0, header = 0, index_col=[0], skiprows= [0,1])   
names = df7.columns.tolist()
```

So names contains all my column heading as a list.
When I take one column at a time and use a function: strftime, then it works.

```
names[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I get the desied result which the format I want. But I want to run a loop so that all 31 columns cab be done in one code. As the first column heading is a string variable "time" so I am leaving column 0 when using a loop. I am using the following code:

```
for i in names[1:33]: 
    i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print (i)
```

But then nothing is actually happening and the format is still the same.
I also tried another way but it is also not working:

```
for i in names:
    if i is type(datetime.datetime):
        i.strftime('%Y-%M-%d')
    else:
        pass
```

It is also not working. I am not even getting any error. Any advices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that [**`strftime`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) does not function `inplace` in itself. So, you should probably be doing `i=i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` to see any effect when you `print` the outputs.

Here's an effective way to accomplish the same process:

1) If all the columns are of type `datetime64[ns]` as you've mentioned, you can use `strftime` and remember to assign these changes back to the `.columns` attribute:

```
df.columns = df.columns.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Also, could make use of [**`.date`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) attribute which simply throws back it's date part and discards the time.

```
df.columns = df.columns.date
```

2) Incase of mixed `dtypes` (combination of dtypes) present, you could then filter these columns on their type with the help of a custom function on [**`map`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) method:

```
import datetime

mapper = lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x
df.columns = df.columns.map(mapper)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nickil! I think both the methods are really good both for me the second one worked perfectly. Because I had one column as string so thats why df.column = df.colomns.date did not work but the second one was on the mark. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert your columns dtype to `string` (`object`) - use [@Nickil's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908141/5741205).

If you want to keep columns in `datetime64` dtype and strip time you can use [normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) method:

```
In [79]: df
Out[79]:
   2017-01-01 08:00:00  2017-01-02 09:00:00
0                    1                    2
1                    3                    4

In [80]: df.columns.dtype
Out[80]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [81]: df.columns.normalize()
Out[81]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [82]: df.columns = df.columns.normalize()

In [83]: df
Out[83]:
   2017-01-01  2017-01-02
0           1           2
1           3           4

In [84]: df.columns.dtype
Out[84]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

**UPDATE:** small demonstration of how `.normalize()` method strips the time part:

```
In [91]: x = pd.DataFrame({'ts':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', freq='999999S', periods=5)})

In [92]: x
Out[92]:
                   ts
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1 2017-01-12 13:46:39
2 2017-01-24 03:33:18
3 2017-02-04 17:19:57
4 2017-02-16 07:06:36

In [93]: x.ts.dt.normalize()
Out[93]:
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-12
2   2017-01-24
3   2017-02-04
4   2017-02-16
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Setup:**

```
"2017-01-01 08:00:00"  "2017-01-02 09:00:00"
                    1                     2
                    3                     4

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

In [114]: df.columns.dtype
Out[114]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [115]: df
Out[115]:
   2017-01-01 08:00:00  2017-01-02 09:00:00
0                    1                    2
1                    3                    4

In [116]: df.columns = df.columns.normalize()

In [117]: df
Out[117]:
   2017-01-01  2017-01-02
0           1           2
1           3           4
```

Comment: Doesn't `normalize` restore time to `00:00:00` (midnight)? I don't think it eliminates them from the `datetime` object. See `df` after assigning.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, yes, but it will be shown without the time part: `DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)`

Comment: @NickilMaveli, what do you mean saying `See df after assigning` - am i missing something?

Comment: No, if the OP simply wanted to track these columns separately as `datetime` dtype, then your solution fits perfectly. Also, the `DF` would contain the time part and I wonder how it isn't shown at cell no. 83. Sorry, wasn't online to comment at once :-)

Comment: @NickilMaveli, i've added a small snippet, which demonstrates how `.normalize()` cuts off the time part (and doesn't show it)

Comment: It's strange when I tried it in pan-`0.19.2`, py-`3.5`, the columns appear with an extra `00:00:00`. That's the reason I was asking you all these while. Your updated snippet works fine however.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, this is really interesting - i can't reproduce described by you behaviour - see "Setup" section

Comment: Still the same for me. Maybe someone having a similar configuration can confirm.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, thanks for checking! I was sure it works like that for everyone - obviously it's not the case. BTW: I'm using `python: 3.5.2.final.0` (Win64), `pandas: 0.19.2`

Comment: OK, I suppose this is a display issue cause when I use `print (df)` it gives me the right result. But when I display them as a table image, then it becomes erroneous. Also, `x.ts.dt.normalize().iloc[0]` should give you a timestamp object with `00:00:00`, right?

Comment: @NickilMaveli, yes `x.ts.dt.normalize().iloc[0]` gives me: `Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me ;-)