# How can I rename a column name which is of datetime type?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The code

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
for col in df.columns.tolist():
  print(col)
  print(type(col))
```

gives this output:

```
Name
<class 'str'>
2008-03-31 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2009-03-31 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2010-03-31 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2011-03-31 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2012-03-31 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I want to rename/format the column name from 2008-03-31 00:00:00 to 31-03-2008

When I do

```
df.rename(columns = {'2008-03-31 00:00:00' : '31-03-2008'}, inplace =True)
```

It does not work and the column name remains 2008-03-31 00:00:00 only.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908141/15160601), you can use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

or [`.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.date
```

Comment: the link shared in your answer helped me to resolve the renaming of the columns. Thanks

Comment: mapper = lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x
df.columns = df.columns.map(mapper)
I used this code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem very well, but try this

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
print("Today [Y-M-D] -> ", today)
today_D_M_Y = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print("Today [D-M-Y] -> ", today_D_M_Y)
```